# How to correctly call models in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My Chefs Model is linked to my Meals Model through chef_id.  I am displaying information about the chef, and would also like to show information about his meals.  I have not been able to figure out the correct way to call it in the controller.  Any ideas?

chef controller:

```
def index
    @chefs=Chef.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @meals = ????? Cant figure out how to call this
end
```

Index.html.erb

```
<div class = 'chef'>
    <div class = 'row'> 


               <% @chefs.each do |chef| %>
                <%= render chef %>

            <% end %>


    </div>
</div>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

_chef partial

```
<div class = 'span4'>
    <div class = 'chef-box'>
        <h2><center><%= link_to chef.name, chef %></center></h2>
        <h2><center>"<%= chef.description %>"</center></h2>
        <h2><center><%= THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY INFORMATION ON MEALS %></center></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does you `Chef` model have a `has_many` property for `Meal`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to access the `@meals`, than you can get it just by for an instance of `@chef`:

```
@meals = @chef.meals
```

given that you have defined the `association` in the `Chef` class like following:

```
class Chef < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meals

  #rest of the code
end
```

Have a look at Active Record Associations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

So, Here I am just giving an example of how to use it in views, you may have to correct it:
in _chef partial

```
<div class = 'span4'>
    <div class = 'chef-box'>
        <h2><center><%= link_to chef.name, chef %></center></h2>
        <h2><center>"<%= chef.description %>"</center></h2>
              <% chef.meals.each do |meal| %>
                 <h2><center><%= meal.information %></center></h2>
            <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will need to call correct attribute of meal in above sample code.

Comment: My associations are correct. But when I declare @meals = @chef.meals I get an **undefined method `meals' error**.

Comment: @user2908778: Updated answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  Could you maybe explain why I couldn't just call <h2><%= chef.meals.meal_name %></h2>.  Why do I have to put it in a block?

Comment: because `chef.meals` returns an array of active record relations(`meals`), you will have to iterate over it to get `meal_name` of each meal. If you had `has_one` realation, it would had worked fine.

Comment: Ahh interesting.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned – first and foremost make sure the relation is set up in your chef model:

```
class Chef < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meals
end
```

Then you can call any `Chef.meals`, whether that's in your controller as:

```
def index
  @chef = Chef.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @meals = @chef.meals
end
```

Or just in your view:

```
<div class = 'span4'>
    <div class = 'chef-box'>
        <h2><center><%= link_to chef.name, chef %></center></h2>
        <h2><center>"<%= chef.description %>"</center></h2>
        <h2>Has <%= pluralize(chef.meals.size, 'meal') %></h2>
        <% chef.meals.each do |meal| %>
          <% meal.name %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of note – since `Chef` is a model name, you should be able to render your `_chef.html.erb` more cleanly with simply:

```
<div class = 'chef'>
    <div class = 'row'> 
      <%= render @chef %>
    </div>
</div>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

Note that `@chef` is singular to match your controller, you could also pass it a collection `<%= render @chefs %>` if that's what's set up in your controller, and it will do render each chef separately.

Comment: Thanks.  This works well.  Could you maybe explain why I couldn't just call <h2><%= chef.meals.meal_name %></h2>. Why do I have to put it in a block?

Comment: Because what happens when a chef has more than one meal? You could however do `<%= render chef.meals %>` if you have a `_meal.html.erb` file